# Django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection default doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm trying to connect the **mongo(v4.0.3)db** with **django(v1.11)** using **mongoengine(0.6.0)** driver. It is showing connection does not exist.

my settings.py file is as  follows:

```
import os

import mongoengine

dbname = 'newdb'

mongoengine.connect(dbname, host='127.0.0.1', port = 27017)

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = ''

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mdbcapp',
 ]

 MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'multiple_databses_connections.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [

    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
 ]

 WSGI_APPLICATION = 'multiple_databses_connections.wsgi.application'

 DATABASES = {

    'dfault': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME'  : ''
       }


 AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [

    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I'm getting following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 22, in 
>   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 363, in execute_from_command_line
>           utility.execute()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 337, in execute
>           django.setup()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/**init**.py", line 27,
>   in setup
>           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
>   108, in populate
>           app_config.import_models()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line
>   202, in import_models
>           self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>           **import**(name)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
>   line 4, in 
>           from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py",
>   line 52, in 
>           class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 124, in **new**
>           new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 330, in add_to_class
>           value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
>   line 214, in contribute_to_class
>           self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/**init**.py", line
>   33, in **getattr**
>           return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208,
>   in **getitem**
>           self.ensure_defaults(alias)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 178,
>   in ensure_defaults
>           raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)
>       django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection default doesn't exist

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you update your question with your `DATABASES` setting? The sensitive items can be replaced. And make sure that you can connect to your database with mongo client.

Comment: As you can see, `DATABASES['default']` is empty. Wish this [django mongodb docs](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/settings.html) can help you. PS: Indentation with 4 spaces can make part of your text look like code.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME'  : 'newdb',
        'USER': 'admin',  
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',  
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  
        'PORT': '27017',  
        #'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,
      }

Comment: i tried  above but i got theese errors .,, Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named util

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using only the Mongo engine. But in the settings file, the database ENGINE key is mandatory. Add this line in `ENGINE`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
     }
}
```

But it may throw an error like database improperly configured which is ignorable.

For more information ref link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#backend

Comment: DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', 'NAME' : 'newdb', 'USER': 'admin', 'PASSWORD': 'admin', 'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 'PORT': '27017', #'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False, }

Comment: i tried above but i got theese errors .,, Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of: 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3' Error was: No module named util

Comment: djano_mongodb_engine is the third party package. have you installed that?

Comment: By default django doesn't has the database engine for mongodb. so there are third party libraries which will provide mongo database engine for django.

if you don't want to go with third party plugins for mongodb engine we must provide dummy database engine for  database key in settings file

Comment: @vekatesh , yeah, i have installed it

Answer (score 0):

Default settings for **Sqlite**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
}
```

**Settings for MySQL**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'my_db_name',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'3306'
  }
 }
```